# MongoDB script fails to load, but code works in Mongo shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following script (script.js):

```
    categoricalVars = db.frekvencija_ctg.find().toArray();
​
    db.ctg.find().forEach(e => {
        db.emb_ctg.insert({ ...e, frekvencija: categoricalVars });
    });
```

When I try to load it in Mongo shell via load("script.js"), I get the following error:

`[js] SyntaxError: illegal character :`

If I run these expressions in Mongo shell one by one with copy/paste, they work and I get desired result. What is wrong in script?

Answer (score 1):

I have got this error before and I have resolved this by removing the braces from the arrow function passed to the `forEach()` method.
Try changing your script to something like this

```js
categoricalVars = db.frekvencija_ctg.find().toArray();
​
db.ctg.find().forEach(function(e){
    var obj = {...e};
    obj.frekvencija = categoricalVars;
    db.emb_ctg.insert(obj);
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Try 
```js
db.ctg.find().map(function(e){ db.emb_ctg.insert({...e, frekvencija: categoricalVars})});
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error log? It says there is an Illegal character `:` in the script. I only see it being used in the `insert` method for the `frekvencija` property of the object being inserted

Comment: I made another edit to the answer @Martin . Let me know if this works or not

Comment: I tried the last edit, but it still returns the same error. Where am I looking for log? I tried C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\log\mongod.log, but I don't see any errors related to this in there.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using an old version of node that doesn't support fancy syntax. Either udgrade node or use old school syntax like :

```
    var categoricalVars = db.frekvencija_ctg.find().toArray();
​
    db.ctg.find().forEach(function(e){
        db.emb_ctg.insert(Object.assign({},e, {frekvencija: categoricalVars }));
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code and it still returns the same error. I checked node version (typed node -v) in cmd and it says v12.13.1